# Extending a user defined class

Tags: objective-c, class, super

I created a class called Box.  I now understand that it is also a class defined in objective C.  My Box class compiles without error and can be called by consumer classes.  Now, I wish to extend the My box class.  I get the error "Conflicting super class name 'Box'".  Is there any way to tell XCode to extend the class I wrote?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Please show the code that is causing your issue.

Comment: For extending class you can use categories and extensions. Check this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your question, but you can try using categories. Categories are an alternative to subclassing, and allow you to add methods to a class.

This is how you would create a category for your Box class:

```
@interface Box (categoryName)
//New methods go here
@end

@implementation Box (categoryName)
//New methods implementation goes here
@end
```